# How to mysql distinct one of many count fields when GROUP BY doesn't work?

Tags: mysql

I've a database with products, manufactors and categories of this products and information about name of manufactors, products and if those products have images.

But in this database are duplicated products with different IDs. Only thing I can identify them is their name.

Now I've a query where I want see how many products per manufactorer and per category were in my database and count also the number of products with images.

```
-----------------------------------------------------
| manufactor | category | products | productsImages |
|------------|----------|----------|----------------|
|   manu-1   |  cat-1   |    5     |       3        |
|------------|----------|----------|----------------|
|   manu-1   |  cat-2   |    15    |       8        |
|------------|----------|----------|----------------|
|   manu-2   |  cat-1   |    11    |       0        |
|------------|----------|----------|----------------|
|   manu-3   |  cat-2   |    5     |       4        |
|------------|----------|----------|----------------|
|   manu-3   |  cat-3   |    9     |       4        |
|------------|----------|----------|----------------|
```

My approach looks like:

```
SELECT m.`name` AS manufactor,
       pg.`name` AS category,
       COUNT(p.`name`) AS products,
       COUNT(pi.`idImage`) AS productsImages
FROM `product` AS p
LEFT JOIN `product_image` AS pi ON pi.`idProduct` = p.`id`
INNER JOIN `manufacturer` AS m ON m.`id` = p.`idManufacturer`
INNER JOIN `product_groupname` AS pg ON pg.`id` = p.`idProductGroup`
GROUP BY p.`idManufacturer`, p.`idProductGroup`
ORDER BY m.`name`, p.`idProductGroup`;
```

I can't group by `p.name` because then I'd get a result row for each product.
Do `COUNT(DISTINCT(p.`name`))` didn't help either.

So any suggestions or will I have do to subqueries?

Comment: Why doesn't `count(distinct p.name)` work?

Comment: Okay, it works. I just saw that same count of effected rows was on both queries. But that's correct, I had to check the numbers at products. Thanks for your comment - that enlighted me ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to count the distinct names where `` pi.`idImage` IS NOT NULL `` you can use the following:

```
SELECT m.`name` AS manufactor,
       pg.`name` AS category,
       COUNT(DISTINCT p.`name`) AS products,
       COUNT(DISTINCT CASE 
             WHEN pi.`idImage` IS NOT NULL THEN p.`name` 
             ELSE NULL 
       END) AS productsImages
FROM `product` AS p
LEFT JOIN `product_image` AS pi ON pi.`idProduct` = p.`id`
INNER JOIN `manufacturer` AS m ON m.`id` = p.`idManufacturer`
INNER JOIN `product_groupname` AS pg ON pg.`id` = p.`idProductGroup`
GROUP BY p.`idManufacturer`, p.`idProductGroup`
ORDER BY m.`name`, p.`idProductGroup`;
```

Answer (score 1):

See comments on question - distinct on p.name is the solution.

```
SELECT m.`name` AS manufactor,
       pg.`name` AS category,
       COUNT(DISTINCT(p.`name`)) AS products,
       COUNT(pi.`idImage`) AS productsImages
FROM `product` AS p
LEFT JOIN `product_image` AS pi ON pi.`idProduct` = p.`id`
INNER JOIN `manufacturer` AS m ON m.`id` = p.`idManufacturer`
INNER JOIN `product_groupname` AS pg ON pg.`id` = p.`idProductGroup`
GROUP BY p.`idManufacturer`, p.`idProductGroup`
ORDER BY m.`name`, p.`idProductGroup`;
```